# How to dynamically change the react element in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to refactor some legacy code. The use case is this. Someone previously had created a new component that basically had all the exact same attributes as the old component. The render method returns either old or new based on a flag, but the attribute values are all the same. This results in many redundant lines that were copy pasted.

```
  return (
         isSomeBoolTrue ? (<OriginalComponent a={a} b={b} ..... z={z} />):
                          (<NewComponent a={a} b={b} ..... z={z} />)
    );
```

I'd like some way to remove the duplicate attributes and have it look something like this:

```
return (isSomeBoolTrue ? (<OriginalComponent):(<NewComponent) a={a} b={b} .... />
```

Comment: Does both component receive the same props.?

Comment: Right now they do, but it is possible that as the new component is developed over time they might diverge slightly

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following approach.

```js
const SelectedComponent = isSomeBoolTrue ? OriginalComponent : NewComponent;
return <SelectedComponent a={a} b={b} z={z} />
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the props into an object, then spread the object into the each component's props while using the conditional operator.

```
const propsToPassDown = { a, b, z };
return (
  isSomeBoolTrue
    ? <OriginalComponent {...{ propsToPassDown }} />
    : <NewComponent {...{ propsToPassDown }} />
);
```

Another approach is to use `React.createElement` instead of JSX, allowing you to use the conditional operator when selecting the component to pass as the first argument.

```
return React.createElement(
  isSomeBoolTrue ? OriginalComponent : NewComponent,
  { a, b, z },
  null
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! When I was asking this question I wasn't even sure if my title made sense, but both solutions you provided were exactly what I was looking for